# V3.16.3 vector menu doesn't work

Tags: vector, context-menu

Installed Linux Ubuntu version 3.16.3 and want to split a state parcels file (95 counties), but when I click on the Vector menu item nothing happens. Have used this feature successfully before in an earlier version (don't remember which).  Also an earlier version had the ability to split out just one county by an option to specify which one, which seems to have now disappeared? Have reloaded v3.16 and problem still exists (can't seem to install 3.18)

Comment: Have you deactivated somehow the Processing Plugin? See unde Menu Plugins and re-activate it, if the case.

Comment: Are you using QGIS or something else?

Comment: Bingo -  plug in was deactivated -- Thanks